# Poco Timer Example

Tags: c++, linux, timer, poco

The following was asked by a coworker and after poking around the internet and not finding a good answer it seemed like a good question for here:

*I am using POCO timers in my embedded code(running on Linux). The timers are a part of the Foundation component. The timers have three basic functions:*

```
Timer.start();
Timer.stop();
Timer.restart();
```

*I am trying to stop and then restart my timers and I can not get it to work...  ...I have looked at all of the POCO samples and examples and there is nothing for timer.restart().*

Does anyone have any insight into this, or a working code example stopping and restarting the timers? Even though the callback function isn't running, the timer will start and stop, but restart doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: How many threads does the system allow?

Answer (score 7):

Ok, since asking this question I've inherited my coworker's project and found the answer myself.

```
//use restart for an already running timer, to restart it
Timer.restart();
```

If your timer is already stopped and you need to restart, you need to reset the periodic interval first, the following is the Poco example with a few lines of my own added to it. This compiles and restarts a timer.

```
#include "Poco/Timer.h"
#include "Poco/Thread.h"
#include "Poco/Stopwatch.h"
#include <iostream>


using Poco::Timer;
using Poco::TimerCallback;
using Poco::Thread;
using Poco::Stopwatch;


class TimerExample
{
public:
        TimerExample()
        {
                _sw.start();
        }

        void onTimer(Timer& timer)
        {
                std::cout << "Callback called after " << _sw.elapsed()/1000 << "      milliseconds." << std::endl;
        }

private:
        Stopwatch _sw;
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{    


    TimerExample example;
    TimerCallback<TimerExample> callback(example, &TimerExample::onTimer);

    Timer timer(250, 500);

    timer.start(callback);

    Thread::sleep(5000);

    timer.stop();

    std::cout << "Trying to restart timer now" << std::endl;

    timer.setStartInterval(250);
    timer.setPeriodicInterval(500);
    timer.start(callback);

    Thread::sleep(5000);

    timer.stop();


    return 0;
 }
```